# Bundle .app file in Xcode project OS X

Tags: xcode, macos

Is there anyway to bundle an existing .app file into an Xcode project on OS X? I basically want to create a wrapper for an existing application to do registration for copy protection.

thanks 
Scott

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that's not possible as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

The default target membership rules for .app bundles inside projects is to copy them into your application's Resources directory. If this works for you, just drag and drop the app you care about on your project.

Keep in mind that on the technical side, this could cause issues with code signing and Mac App Store receipts if you are not the developer of the application that you are embedding. On the legal side, it's also possible that you wouldn't be allowed to distribute the embedded application like that.